# How can I draw hashed lines on a bended line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm trying to draw the following figure in TikZ :
[image]

But I've been facing problems on how I can draw the hashed lines on my bended line, and how to eliminate a part of some circle :

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}   %<<< added
\begin{document}    %<<< added

\begin{tikzpicture}[ rotate=5, >=stealth]
\draw[fill=lightgray, opacity=0.3] (2.37,-4.1)circle(0.3);
\draw[fill=lightgray, opacity=0.3] (2.07,-1.71)circle(0.3);
\draw[fill=lightgray, opacity=0.3] (2,0)circle(0.5);
\draw[fill=lightgray, opacity=0.3] (2.18,2.8)circle(0.3);
\draw (0,0) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=1];
\draw (0,0) ellipse [x radius=4, y radius=2];
\draw (0,0) ellipse [x radius=6.5, y radius=4];
\filldraw[black] (0,0) circle(0.02) node[left] {$x_1$};
\draw[smooth] (2.455,4.6)to[bend right=10](2.455,-4.6);
\draw[smooth, gray,thick, ->] (2,0)--(3,0);
\draw[smooth,thick, ->] (2,0)--(1,0);
\filldraw[black] (2,0)circle(0.03) node[right=0.17, above] {$x_3$};
\draw[smooth, gray,thick, ->] (4,0)--(5,0);
\filldraw[black] (2.07,-1.71)circle(0.03)node[right=0.17, above] {$x_2$};
\draw[thick, ->, black] (2.07,-1.71)--(1, -1.99);
\draw[smooth, gray,thick, ->]  (-2.07,-1.71)--(-2.3, -2.4);
\draw[smooth,thick, ->]  (2.18,2.8)--(1.1,3);
\draw[smooth,thick, ->] (2.37,-4.1)--(1.5,-4.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}         %<<< added
```

I've tried the `fill` option while drawing the bended line but it didn't work, is there any solution for this, here's what I'm intending to draw :

[image]

Comment: Please modify your question with a complete [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: @SebGlav what rule did I break in this question ?

Comment: This is not a "rule", just a convenient way to help others to help you without having to write the rest of your code.

Comment: @Med-Elf Please see my edit for your question. I added `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\end{document}` to make your code a (compilable) minimal working example. Please notice that for next questions (if any), because you should help the helpers writing a MWE; the helpers often be lazy/uncomfortable to write such trivial things, they like to help just by copying and then compiling

Comment: @BlackMild Ohh I see now! okay I'm gonna keep this in mind, thanks !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fill a shape with a pattern (using `patterns.meta` library):

[image: dashed bent zone]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[ rotate=5, >=stealth]
    \begin{scope}
            \clip (2.455,4.6)to[bend right=10](2.455,-4.6) -- ([xshift=20pt]2.455,-4.6) to[bend left=10] ([xshift=20pt]2.455,4.6);
            
            \draw[fill=lightgray, opacity=0.3] (2.37,-4.1)circle(0.3);
            \draw[fill=lightgray, opacity=0.3] (2.07,-1.71)circle(0.3);
            \draw[fill=lightgray, opacity=0.3] (2,0)circle(0.5);
            \draw[fill=lightgray, opacity=0.3] (2.18,2.8)circle(0.3);
        
        \end{scope}
        
        
        \draw (0,0) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=1];
        \draw (0,0) ellipse [x radius=4, y radius=2];
        \draw (0,0) ellipse [x radius=6.5, y radius=4];
        
        
        
        \path[fill= white,pattern={Lines[
            angle=30, 
            distance=3pt, 
            line width=0.3pt] },
            pattern color=orange] (2.455,4.6)to[bend right=10](2.455,-4.6) -- ([xshift=-20pt]2.455,-4.6) to[bend left=10] ([xshift=-20pt]2.455,4.6);
            
        \draw[smooth] (2.455,4.6)to[bend right=10](2.455,-4.6);

        
        
        
        \draw[smooth, gray,thick, ->] (2,0)--(3,0);
        \draw[smooth,thick, ->] (2,0)--(1,0);
        \filldraw[black] (2,0)circle(0.03) node[right=0.17, above right] {$x_3$};
        \draw[smooth, gray,thick, ->] (4,0)--(5,0);
        \filldraw[black] (2.07,-1.71)circle(0.03)node[right=0.17, below right] {$x_2$};
        \draw[thick, ->, black] (2.07,-1.71)--(1, -1.99);
        \draw[smooth, gray,thick, ->]  (-2.07,-1.71)--(-2.3, -2.4);
        \draw[smooth,thick, ->]  (2.18,2.8)--(1.1,3);
        \draw[smooth,thick, ->] (2.37,-4.1)--(1.5,-4.3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @SebGlav , by the way adding `fill=white` in the command you showed me will eliminate the undesired part, Thank you again !!

Comment: You should not use `fill=white` because it will be visible on a non white background. I edited my answer to show how to proceed. Create a clipped scope on the right (the same way that I created the dashed zone on the left) and draw the circles into this clipped zone.

Comment: Very impressive! I must to study **tikz**. As I can see, almost anything can be done with it! What are best tutorials about It?

Comment: I started a long time ago by studying examples at [TeXample](https://texample.net/tikz/), then the manual was my bible for some time. Answering to questions on TeX-SX is also a good challenging way of lernaing more.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using the `border` decoration using `decorations.pathreplacing`. You can set the `angle`, `amplitude`, and `segment length` options as you wish.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ rotate=5, >=stealth, decoration={border,segment length=2mm, angle=-60, amplitude=4mm}]
\draw[fill=lightgray, opacity=0.3] (2.37,-4.1)circle(0.3);
\draw[fill=lightgray, opacity=0.3] (2.07,-1.71)circle(0.3);
\draw[fill=lightgray, opacity=0.3] (2,0)circle(0.5);
\draw[fill=lightgray, opacity=0.3] (2.18,2.8)circle(0.3);
\draw (0,0) ellipse [x radius=2, y radius=1];
\draw (0,0) ellipse [x radius=4, y radius=2];
\draw (0,0) ellipse [x radius=6.5, y radius=4];
\filldraw[black] (0,0) circle(0.02) node[left] {$x_1$};
\draw[smooth,postaction={decorate, draw}] (2.455,4.6)to[bend right=10](2.455,-4.6);
\draw[smooth, gray,thick, ->] (2,0)--(3,0);
\draw[smooth,thick, ->] (2,0)--(1,0);
\filldraw[black] (2,0)circle(0.03) node[right=0.17, above] {$x_3$};
\draw[smooth, gray,thick, ->] (4,0)--(5,0);
\filldraw[black] (2.07,-1.71)circle(0.03)node[right=0.17, above] {$x_2$};
\draw[thick, ->, black] (2.07,-1.71)--(1, -1.99);
\draw[smooth, gray,thick, ->]  (-2.07,-1.71)--(-2.3, -2.4);
\draw[smooth,thick, ->]  (2.18,2.8)--(1.1,3);
\draw[smooth,thick, ->] (2.37,-4.1)--(1.5,-4.3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```